# Saved torch model always returns the same prediction regardless of input

Tags: python, model, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

```
import os
import torch
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms, models
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, target_part, transform=None):
        self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.class_mapping = {'S': 0, 'A': 1, 'B': 2}
        self.target_part = target_part

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(self.data.iloc[idx, 0]), f"{self.data.iloc[idx, 0]}_{self.data.iloc[idx, 1]}.jpg")

        part = self.data.iloc[idx, 1]
        if part != self.target_part:
            return None, None

        image = Image.open(img_name)
        rank = self.data.iloc[idx, 2]
        label = self.class_mapping.get(rank, -1)

        if label == -1:
            raise ValueError(f"알파벳 랭크 '{rank}'를 매핑할 수 없습니다.")

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)

        return image, label
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((512, 512)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

batch_size = 20
target_parts = ["back", "front", "keyboard", "monitor"]
models_dict = {}

part_epochs = {
    "back": 50,
    "front": 50,
    "keyboard": 50,
    "monitor": 50
}
for part in target_parts:
    num_epochs = part_epochs.get(part, 10)

    if num_epochs == 0:
        print(f"Skipping training for {part} part...")
        continue

    train_dataset = CustomDataset('/content/drive/MyDrive/train2.csv', '/content/drive/MyDrive/train2', target_part=part, transform=transform)

    train_dataset = [data for data in train_dataset if data[0] is not None]

    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

    model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
    num_features = model.classifier[6].in_features
    model.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(num_features, 3)

    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model.to(device)

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

    models_dict[part] = model
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        model.train()
        running_loss = 0.0
        for batch in train_loader:
            inputs, labels = batch
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            running_loss += loss.item()

        print(f"Training model for {part} part - 에포크 {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, 손실: {running_loss / len(train_loader)}")
from PIL import Image
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

# 이미지 파일 경로 설정
image_paths = {
    "back": '/content/drive/MyDrive/testinput/170612495/170612495_back.jpg',
    "front": '/content/drive/MyDrive/testinput/170612495/170612495_front.jpg',
    "keyboard": '/content/drive/MyDrive/testinput/170612495/170612495_keyboard.jpg',
    "monitor": '/content/drive/MyDrive/testinput/170612495/170612495_monitor.jpg',
}

# 이미지를 텐서로 변환
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((512,512)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

results = {}

for part, image_path in image_paths.items():
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = transform(image)

    model = models_dict[part]  # 이미 학습된 해당 부위의 모델 선택
    model.eval()  # 모델을 평가 모드로 설정
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)  # 배치 차원 추가
    image = image.to(device)
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(image)
    _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
    rank_mapping = {0: 'S', 1: 'A', 2: 'B'}  # 모델 학습 시 사용한 랭크 매핑
    predicted_rank = rank_mapping[predicted.item()]
    results[part] = predicted_rank

print("각 부위별 랭크 결과:", results)
```

We learned and tested an AI model that returns a damage rank for each part when an image of each part of the laptop is entered. After training and testing, I'm returning rank values ​​based on the images, which is what I want.

```
# 모델 저장
checkpoint_path = f'/content/drive/MyDrive/vggnettestmodel2.pth'
model.fc = nn.Linear(num_features, 3)
checkpoint = {
    'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(),
    'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
    'classifier.6.weight': model.classifier[6].weight,
    'classifier.6.bias': model.classifier[6].bias
}
torch.save(checkpoint, checkpoint_path)
```

So I saved the model.

```
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
# 모델 아키텍처 생성
loaded_model = models.vgg16(pretrained=False)  # 아키텍처만 생성, 가중치를 로드하지 않음

# 모델 상태 로드
checkpoint = torch.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/vggnettestmodel2.pth")

# 모델 상태를 수정하여 클래스 수와 일치하도록 조정
num_features = loaded_model.classifier[6].in_features
loaded_model.classifier[6] = torch.nn.Linear(num_features, 3)  # 클래스 수를 3으로 수정

# "classifier.6" 레이어의 가중치 초기화
if "classifier.6.weight" in checkpoint and "classifier.6.bias" in checkpoint:
    loaded_model.classifier[6].weight = nn.Parameter(checkpoint["classifier.6.weight"])
    loaded_model.classifier[6].bias = nn.Parameter(checkpoint["classifier.6.bias"])
else:
    print("체크포인트에서 'classifier.6' 레이어의 가중치를 찾을 수 없습니다.")

# 저장된 모델의 가중치를 수정된 모델로 복사
loaded_model.load_state_dict(checkpoint, strict=False)

loaded_model.eval()  # 모델을 평가 모드로 설정

# 모델을 디바이스로 이동
loaded_model = loaded_model.to(device)

# 다음은 테스트 부분입니다
for part in target_parts:
    model = loaded_model  # 로드한 모델을 사용
    model.eval()  # 모델을 평가 모드로 설정
    models_dict[part] = model  # 모델을 models_dict에 추가
from PIL import Image
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

# 이미지 파일 경로 설정
image_paths = {
    "back": '/content/drive/MyDrive/testinput/170612495/170612495_back.jpg',
    "front": '/content/drive/MyDrive/testinput/170612495/170612495_front.jpg',
    "keyboard": '/content/drive/MyDrive/testinput/170612495/170612495_keyboard.jpg',
    "monitor": '/content/drive/MyDrive/testinput/170612495/170612495_monitor.jpg',
}

# 이미지를 텐서로 변환
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((512,512)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

results = {}

for part, image_path in image_paths.items():
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = transform(image)

    model = models_dict[part]  # 이미 학습된 해당 부위의 모델 선택
    model.eval()  # 모델을 평가 모드로 설정
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)  # 배치 차원 추가
    image = image.to(device)
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(image)
    _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
    rank_mapping = {0: 'S', 1: 'A', 2: 'B'}  # 모델 학습 시 사용한 랭크 매핑
    predicted_rank = rank_mapping[predicted.item()]
    results[part] = predicted_rank

print("각 부위별 랭크 결과:", results)
```

However, when I load and test the model in a new notebook, it returns an S rank no matter what image I enter. What is the reason?

There doesn't seem to be a problem with learning, but rather a problem with saving or loading, but it's my first time with AI modeling, so it's difficult to figure out the cause.